# Return only one group with OR condition in Regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have to write a Regex to fetch Email Address from a sentence. I want it to be returned with Group 1 only.

Regex:

```
\[mailto:(.+)\]|<(.+@.+\..+)>
```

Input String:

```
Hello my Email Address is <foo@hotmail.com> - Return foo@hotmail.com as Group1.
Hello my Email Address is [mailto: foo@hotmail.com] - Return foo@hotmail.com as Group2.
```

I want if any of the string matches then it should be returned in Group1.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use regular expression:

```
(?=\S+@)([^<\s]+@.*(?=[>\]]))
```

- `(?=\S+@)` Positive lookahead, assert that what follows is any non-whitespace characters followed by `@`.
- `([^<\s]+@.*(?=[>\]]))` Capture group. Capture any non-whitespace, non `^` character followed by `@`, and anything up to either a `]` or `>` character.

You can test the regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/TnOA4r/3).

Comment: Thanks. This expression works for only alphanumeric characters. But Email Address can consists of special characters too such as foo.123@hotmail.com, foo$123@hotmail.com. What about this usecase?

Comment: (?=.+@)(?:[:<])(.+@.+(?=[>\]])) - This seems working.

Answer (score 0):

You could first match either `<` and assert that it ends with `..>` or match  `[mailto:`  and assert that it ends with `]`

To prevent unnecessary backtracking and prevent over matching, you can use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), denoted by `[^`

```
(?:<(?=[^<>]*>)|\[mailto:\s*(?=[^][]*]))([^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.\w{2,})
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `<(?=[^<>]*>)` Match `<` and assert `...>` without any occurrence of `<` or `>` in between
  - `|` Or
  - `\[mailto:\s*` match `[mailto:` followed by optional whitespace chars
  - `(?=[^][]*])` Postive lookahead, assert matching optional chars other than `[` or `]` and match `]`
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s@]+` Match 1+ chars other than @ or a whitespace char
  - `@` Match the @
  - `[^\s@]+\.\w{2,}` Match 1+ chars other than @ or a whitespace char followed by a dot and 2 or more word chars (you can make the TLD as specific as you want)
- `)` Close group 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SbZgEa/1)