# Total excl/incl from string using regexp

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, uipath, positive-lookahead

I've been reading this post [Return only one group with OR condition in Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542531/return-only-one-group-with-or-condition-in-regex) to get an understanding how to get only one group in match. Somehow that does not work on my pattern.

***Here is the used string:***

```
Ledigingen 4 lediging € 32,48 € 50,92 21,00 %
van 01-01-2019 t/m 31-01-2019
Huur 1 Maand € 8,63 € 8,63 21,00 %
toeslag over € 50,42 (21% BTW) € 2,76 21,00 %
(WHITESPACE) Totaal exclusief BTW € 50,18 
BTW hoog (21%) € 50,18 € 50,89 
totaal inclusief BTW € 70,07
```

Currently it extracts each occurence of amount. Is there a way to get only values followed by `[Tt]otaa?l excl/incl BTW`?

I guess I've been using positive/negative lookahead wrong.

Desired output from the given input is:

```
€ 50,18
€ 70,07
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/PuGrqn/6)

**RegEx**

```
(?!<=[tT]otaa?l\s*?.*?)([€$]\s*\d+(?:[,.]\d{0,2})?)
```

Comment: Did you read the regex explanation at regex101?

Comment: [Is this OK](https://regex101.com/r/PuGrqn/7)

Comment: @Toto I am looking for a way to extract only values with this mask €$ dd.dd. And the pattern should be stable in case string has only i.e. totaal incl/totaal excl with or without BTW . I added ([A-Z]{3})*? in your pattern for cases when there is no BTW. But how to get only amount now? https://regex101.com/r/PuGrqn/11

Comment: With [this one](https://regex101.com/r/PuGrqn/13), the amount is found in group 1

Comment: Are you using python or another language?

Comment: Single use of regex, is there a way to extract get only 1st group values? Like for instance here https://regex101.com/r/PuGrqn/16

Comment: If you can use PCRE regex flavour, [here is a way](https://regex101.com/r/PuGrqn/20)

Comment: nice one, although uipath(tool that i use) does not support PCRE, is there any workaround here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UIPath as you mentioned in the comments, you could use:

```
(?<=\b[Tt]otaa?l\s+(?:ex|in)cl[^€$]*)[€$]\s*\d+(?:[,.]\d{1,2})?\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert that to the left is

  - `\b[Tt]otaa?l\s+(?:ex|in)cl` Match the word `totaal` or `Totaal` followed by `excl` or `incl`
  - `[^€$]*` Match optional chars other than `€` or `$`
- `)` Close the lookbehind assertion
- `[€$]` Match one of `€` or `$`
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `\d+(?:[,.]\d{1,2})?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match

See a [.NET regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dekMYy/1)

To also match the  `inclusief BTW`  or  `exclusief BTW`  part, a more specific regex could be:

```
(?<=\b[Tt]otaa?l\s+(?:ex|in)clusief\s+BTW\s+)[€$]\s*\d+(?:[,.]\d{1,2})?\b
```

See another [.NET regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GUyULb/1)